# JavaFX shows formatted text in different format that has passed to show

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to write a JavaFX app that shows in UI formatted text. The problem is showed text is a bit different from what i passed to show. Seems like less spaces, that it is supposed to be.
What can i do wrong?

```
@FXML
public ListView<HBox> buyList;
@FXML
public ListView<HBox> sellList;
```

. . .

```
private ObservableList<HBox> ordersToListItems(List<Order> orders)
{
    ObservableList<HBox> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    orders.forEach(order -> {
        final String assetVolume = order.getAssetVolume() + "$";
        final String limits = order.getLimitFiatMin() + "-" + order.getLimitFiatMax();
        Label priceLabel = new Label(String.format("%-7s", order.getPrice()));
        Label limitsLabel = new Label(String.format("%-12s", limits));
        Label volumeLabel = new Label(String.format("%-20s", assetVolume));
        Label nameLabel = new Label(String.format("%-20s", order.getAdvertiserName()));
        System.out.println(priceLabel.getText() + limitsLabel.getText() + volumeLabel.getText() + nameLabel.getText());
        HBox hbox = new HBox(priceLabel, limitsLabel, volumeLabel, nameLabel);
        items.add(hbox);
    });

    return items;
}
```

. . .

```
buyList.setItems(ordersToListItems(buyOrders));
sellList.setItems(ordersToListItems(sellOrders));
```

Output in console:

[image]

Ouput in `JavaFX` app:

[image]

Comment: The console uses a fixed-width font.  Your app uses a variable-width font.  You can [customize the font with CSS](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont).  Selecting a fixed-width font for display such as `monospace` or `Courier` will allow everything in your listview spaced columns to align as you expect.  Some info on [fixed and variable width fonts](https://azi.medium.com/proportional-vs-monospaced-numbers-when-to-use-which-one-in-order-to-avoid-wiggling-labels-e31b1c83e4d0).

Comment: If you want to line things up in a table or grid in JavaFX, you should use an appropriate layout to do that, instead of relying on a text-based layout. Either a `GridPane` or possibly a `TableView` should work, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: You shouldn't put nodes in the list backing a ListView.  That list should only include data items.  If you want to customize the visuals of the items displayed in the ListView, then use a cell factory that produces [customized cells](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html). (The same is true for TableView if you decide to use that instead).

Comment: You should have `ListView<Order>`, not `ListView<HBox>`, and use the list view cell factory to produce and populate the HBoxes and Labels you need.  Study a [ListView tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm) "Customizing the Content of a List View" for more info.